# Why do my cells shift to the right when my tableView bounce out of the view?

Tags: swift

I added a ***tableView*** with all of my structures and their childs to facilitate the navigation. but somehow my cells shift to the right every time my ***TableView*** bounces out of my view. I uploaded a [gif](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/Y4Dt8wCPZcv8XRVAX0) to show my problem.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/1pRi9Jjg) is the full source code.

---

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StructureNavigationCell", for: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as! StructureNavigationCell
            cell.structureLabel.text = structure.name
            cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant = cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant * CGFloat(self.depthDictionary[structure.id]!)
            return cell
```

---

```
func showList() {
    if treeSource == nil {
        treeSource = StructureTreeSource(projectId:GlobalState.selectedProjectId!)
    }

    //The following piece of code achieves the correct order of structures and their substructures.
    //It is extremely bad designed and rather expensive with lots of structures and should
    //therefore be refactored!
    if let strctrs = getStructures() {
        var sortedStructures : [Structure] = []
        while(sortedStructures.count != strctrs.count) {
            for strct in strctrs {
                if let _ = sortedStructures.index(of: strct) {
                    continue
                } else {
                    depthDictionary[strct.id] = getDepthOfNode(structure: strct, depth: 1)
                    if let structures = getStructures() {
                        if let parent = structures.first(where: {$0.id == strct.parentId}) {
                            if let index = sortedStructures.index(of: parent) {
                                sortedStructures.insert(strct, at: index+1)
                            }
                        } else {
                            sortedStructures.insert(strct, at: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        structures.value = sortedStructures

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Someone got an idea why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table view cells are *reused*. This means that sometimes old cells will be dequeued when you call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`. Every time the table view needs to display a new cell, it calls `cellForRowAt`, in which you then configure a cell and return it. You need to keep in mind that this cell that you are configuring might be an old cell.

The problematic line of code is this:

```
cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant = cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant * CGFloat(self.depthDictionary[structure.id]!)
```

If `cell` is an old cell, its `spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant` would have already been set the first time it is configured, so now you are increasing it again, when it is shown the second time, which causes it to move to the right even further.

You should replace `cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant` with a (named) constant, say, `10` (or whatever the initial value of `cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant` is), so that the variable doesn't get set a larger and larger number each time the method is called:

```
cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant = 10 * CGFloat(self.depthDictionary[structure.id]!)
```